# How to write code for landscape or portrait modes in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

How to write code for landscape or portrait through programatically.i need to set my app only run in portrait mode only.please tell me .

Answer (score 1):

You can change it and make it **run only in portrait** in your **`package.appxmanifest`** file.
But please do note, this won't work on the emulator, or any other device without a hardware accelerometer.

[image: Settings]

**[More](http://www.marauderzstuff.com/PermaLink,guid,3a0b6d85-9991-4d85-be21-e5aae3099df3.aspx)**

Comment: I think you would have to hand that over to a different application. There is always `https://docs.google.com/viewer` which formats and displays your PDF for you on a `webBrowserControl`, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set SupportedOrientations , Orintation property to Portrait  (in xaml).